# What would have to be considered when designing a humanoid species with extra limbs?

Tags: humans, anatomy, body-modification

My dad was talking about some book where these humans had one big arm and two smaller arms, and it got me thinking. What if humans had two extra arms? And not big ones like the Ben 10 alien, but rather two smaller ones like the Xenomorph Queen (for smaller detailed work?) that would fold across the torso when not in use.

Comment: As much or as little as you want to consider. No more no less.

Comment: It's worth making use of the search facility at the top of the page. You'll find there are plenty of questions relating to hexapods etc.: [Search "hexapod human"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=hexapod+human) gives us those to flick through, ["Extra limbs humans"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=extra+limbs+human) gives some more. Can you narrow things down a lot, and clarify what exactly you're after and ensure what you're asking isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest considerations are:

The Skeleton and the Musculature.

So let's go with Skeleton first:

We need somewhere to put the new Shoulder joint - this needs to be a ball and socket type joint if we are going to have any proper strength and any form of mobility on these new arms - but this leads to our first problem - Where does such a joint attach?

If we attach it to the ribs, we will severely impact our ability to breath (the Ribs need to be flexible to help the lungs expand/contract), If we do further down on the Floating ribs - this is even worse - as we might end up cracking a rib if we try to use these arms too hard.

We could perhaps do it from the front, mounted off the Sternum - however this would massively inhibit our ability to bend over and it would require this feature to be Sexually Dimorphic (Can't have a Womb grow a featus if there's a great set of joints in the way).

But let's assume that we can mount off the Sternum.

Then we've got to add the Muscles to support and move these arms - we've got a bit of space where the obliques are, could probably mount some strands to the pelvis and to the Sternum - would completely change the profile of the torso and given the length and the mounting points, these arms would be significantly weaker than the main arms - but I think it could be possible.

Of course, you could re-design the Ribcage/Torso entirely to add a second mounting point, but at that point - we aren't really talking humans anymore - they would be completely genetically engineered creatures from a Human base.

Comment: I suspect there's a brainpower consideration too. Extra limbs = that much more brainpower assigned to limb control rather than cognitive thinking. Part of why humans got to be so smart is that we are relatively simple: straightforward digestive system, no sonar, small bodies (relative to, say, elephants)....we have a lot of brainpower we can spend on thinking. Adding physical complexity might have made us dumber.